# Static data member in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A() { cout << "A's constructor called " << endl; }
};

class B
{
    static A a;
public:
    B() { cout << "B's constructor called " << endl; }
    static A getA() { return a; }
};

A B::a; // definition of a

int main()
{
    B b1, b2, b3;
    A a = b1.getA();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
B's constructor called 
B's constructor called
```

Here even when A is not the base class of B, why A's constructor is being invoked first?

Comment: Static members get initialized before `main` begins.

Comment: Not too familiar (any more) with C++ but doesn't B have a static member of type A? Wouldn't any reference/access to B require it to be statically initialized first, which would thus call the A constructor?

Comment: This is a code i found in geeksforgeeks and posted here for better explanation.

Comment: As @LasseV.Karlsen said, you've a static object of A inside class B. That's why A's constructor is called. If you remove `static` keyword from your code, then you'll see that for each object of B, the constructor of A is called.

Comment: @user2357112 That means even if there is nothing in the main A's constructor will be invoked. I ran the program with empty main and yes its giving this result. Thank you :)

Comment: @Zindarod I understand the point that A's constructor should be invoked as it is instantiated inside B but my question was why it is getting called before B's constructor even when it is not the base class.

Comment: Wouldn't you expect any static members of B to be initialzied before the first *instance* constructor of B is called?

Comment: You have `A B::a;` in the file, so of course an `A` is constructed at that point. That's the whole reason for having that line.

Comment: Thanks @Bo Persson. I didn't think it in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for why A's constructor is called *once*, and *first*, as part of your code is as follows:

1. `B` have a static field of type `A` (not a pointer, a real, live, instance, of type `A`).
2. As such, any usage of `B` should require it to be statically initialized once
3. Thus the static field, of type `A`, will need to be initialized
4. Thus, `A`'s constructor is called in order to do so.